Why Trino fault tolerant execution is too slow?
I have 50 worker node in my trino cluster.
Each has 40 cpu and 120GB ram.
I set fault tolerant like this:
retry-policy=TASK
fault-tolerant-execution-task-memory=10GB


exchange-manager.name=hdfs
exchange.base-directories=hadoop-master:9000/exchange-spooling-directory
hdfs.config.resources=/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

When i run query it works like : (hive query)
total 5000 splits
when it comes to last 50 split it waits so much time. there are 9 failed tasks but query still continue but never ends.
If i close fault tolerant query finishes about 15seconds but otherwise it never ends (wait for 4 minute)
is it normal or how can i set fault tolerant parameters?
